# Photoshop CC html5 panel document preview

Tags: html, panel, document, photoshop, preview

I am developing a HTML5 panel for Photoshop CC on Windows 7 x64 which requires a preview image of the current document.

At the moment I am saving a small thumbnail image to the users 'temp' folder using the code:

```
window.cep.fs.makedir()
```

This image file is then used in a canvas element which all works fine.

The problem I have is that the contents of the document will change so the 'canvas' element needs to be updated with the new image but  while the new image saves ok, re-loading into the canvas still uses the old version.

I am clearing the canvas each time its displayed before loading the image via an onload function but the 'cached' version remains. I have been unable to find a 'clear cache' solution which would be the ideal answer.

The only way I have been able to overcome this problem is to save the image with a different filename each time to effectively force a refresh of the canvas.

This also works fine but does mean I end up with a folder full of redundant image files.

Is there a better way to create a preview of the document contents without saving a new image file every time?
I thought I may be able to use the clipboard but I cannot find a way to get the clipboard contents into a canvas element, is this even possible?

I have also tried to delete the old file first via cep.fs.remove(), cep.fs.DeleteFileOrDirectory() and various other combinations but nothing seems to work except makedir().

I cannot use jQuery so it needs a pure javascript solution, if there is one.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
window.cep.fs.DeleteFile()
```

This wasn't in the same documentation I was reading when I found cep.fs.DeleteFileOrDirectory() but it works fine.

The question still remains though, is there a better way to create a flattened preview image from the activeDocument?